# WPF: Binding not working inside ContentControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I've been on this for hours now and I am not getting what is not working or how it is working. A bit of explanation would be appreciate how all this behave.

I'm trying to add a trigger based on another cell content and it is working fine if I forget the binding part.

My problem is actually the Binding itself. It simply doesn't work if it's inside the ContentControl.

**My Code:**

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CBW_Type}" Value="Text">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CBW_Content, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I tried the below and it work as expected (Without the trigger). The data get into place just fine.

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CBW_Content, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I searched a lot of quite a few have solved this with the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged but it didn't work for me.

Anyone can tell what is not working once I embed the binding inside the ContentControl?

Regards,

Comment: Just found the answer. I needed to add `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">` so the ContentControl is not empty I guess. If anyone can put a light on that one, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

> Just found the answer. I needed to add  so the ContentControl is not empty I guess. If anyone can put a light on that one, I'd appreciate it.

The `DataContext` of the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentControl` is the `Content` of the `ContentControl`. So for your binding to the `CBW_Content` property to work, you need to set or bind the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` to an instance of an object where the `CBW_Content` property is defined.

In this case this is the corresponding object in the `ItemsSource` collection of the `DataGrid`. That's why `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">` works.

If you don't set or bind the `Content` property so something, there is nothing to bind to and that's why your `DataTrigger` didn't work.

Hopes that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`ContentTemplate` is to provide a different template for the `Content`, no `Content` => `ContentTemplate clueless`. So, you can also replace `ContentTemplate` with `Content` and remove `DataTemplate` like this in your original code :

```
          <Setter Property="Content">
              <Setter.Value>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CBW_Content, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
```